# Convert object with two string parameters to comma separated string

Tags: c#

This is my object and i'm getting list of this object:

```
public class MeetingTypeModel
{
    public string MeetingTypeId { get; set; }
    public string MeetingTypeName { get; set; }
}

List<MeetingTypeModel> MeetingTypeList
```

I want to convert it into format:

```
({ "1": "Bangladesh", "2": "Belgium"})
```

Comment: Convert your list into a Dictionary pre serializing.

Comment: just asking all of you guys can he achieve this by overriding the String.Join() method?

Comment: @Lucifer what do you mean, by overriding `String.Join()` method?

Comment: we can have a list<string> in a CSV format by using String.Join() what if user uses that logic and creates his own method to achieve `({ "1": "Bangladesh", "2": "Belgium"})` .I am just asking can we or can we not?
c#

Comment: @Lucifer you can't override `string.Join`, it is a static method on a `Type`. 

you could create a different type `StringExtensions` and an Extension method called `public static string Join(this string, bool myMethodSignatureIsDifferent, params string[] args)` as some sort of overload concept to `string.Join` more or less.  but that would still not be static method on `string`. and it would only serve to confuse people.

Comment: Do you need to effectively generate a JSON representation of your list or is it just a coincidence that you need the output to be formatted this way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you **shouldn't** create a json *Dictionary*

```
var temp = MeetingTypeList.Select(x => $"\"{x.MeetingTypeId}\" : \"{x.MeetingTypeName}\"");
var json = $"{{ {string.Join(", ", temp)} }}";
```

They way you **should** create a json *Dictionary*

```
var dict = MeetingTypeList.ToDictionary(x => x.MeetingTypeId, x => x.MeetingTypeName); 
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented);
```

**Update** from *Brett Caswells* comments

> Some considerations to this.
>
> - We cannot guarantee Distinction with MeetingTypeId MeetingTypeName pairing (it doesn't likely though).
> - Whether "(" is prepended and ")" appended to the result of this serialization.

If you need the extra parenthesises

```
json = $"({json})";
```

- https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Comment: this is likely the best answer, though there are some considerations to this.  the first is that we cannot guarantee Distinction with `MeetingTypeId` `MeetingTypeName` pairing (it doesn't likely though).

Comment: Second consideration is based on whether "(" is prepended and ")" appended to the result of this serialization.  I'm not familiar with parenthesis in Json myself.

Comment: @BrettCaswell both valid points

Comment: @BrettCaswell updated and attributed

Answer (score 1):

Simply add reference to **Newtonoft.Json** and add `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

```
var MeetingTypeList = new List<MeetingTypeModel>();
// add data to list
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MeetingTypeList);
```

Comment: you are also going to have to decorate the properties with `[JsonProperty("1")]` and `[JsonProperty("2")]`...

Comment: this is probably incorrect. the result output OP put forward uses value of `MeetingTypeId ` property as a field

Comment: to clarify, wouldn't the result of this serialization be: `[{ "MeetingTypeId" : "1", "MeetingTypeName" : "Bangladesh" }, {"MeetingTypeId" : "2", "MeetingTypeName" : "Belgium" }]`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid using external libraries, you could do it item by item like the following:

```
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
    SB.Append("({");
    for(int i=0; i<MeetingTypeList.Count; i++) {
        MeetingTypeModel mtm = MeetingTypeList[i];

        SB.AppendFormat("\"{0}\":"\"{1}\", mtm.MeetingTypeId, mtm.MeetingTypeName);
        if {i<MeetingTypeList.Count -1) {
          SB.Append(",");
        }
    }
    SB.Append("})");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through list and by using StringBuilder, you can generate expected output

```
public string GetString(List<MeetingTypeModel> MeetingTypeList)
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("({");
int i = 1;
foreach(MeetingTypeModel item in MeetingTypeList){

    sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\" : \"{1}\"" , item.MeetingTypeId, item.MeetingTypeName);
    //To not append last comma
    if(i != MeetingTypeList.Count)
        sb.Append(",");
    i++;
}
sb.Append("})");
return sb.ToString();
}
```

POC: [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cSnPp9)

Comment: Your code will have an extra comma

Comment: @SSS I updated my answer, why downvote, I can work on your suggestions

Comment: your answer is correct, and doesn't warrant a downvote; but, I wouldn't upvote this, since I consider it to be low quality by virtue of using `StringBuilder`.  `StringBuilder` does have it's role, but the better answers here are going to involve serialization.

Comment: I didn't downvote, someone else did

Comment: @BrettCaswell, I agreed that serialization would be elegant approach over function which I wrote. I used `StringBuilder` as it is mutable and having advantages over `string`